# Forza Horizon 4 Keeps on Crashing

Tags: pc, forza-horizon-4

I have recently downloaded Forza Horizon 4, but there is a problem, after I set up my name and click on play Forza Horizon the game gets a grey screen and closes to the Desktop even before it finished loading the map, no error were displayed and I couldn't even see a glimpse of gameplay,
please may I have a solution for this.

Add: I have the minimum amount of ram required for the game.
Add: I am running the game on windows 10 build 1909.

Comment: Might be worth adding a tag for which platform you're playing on as answers will no doubt be platform specific.

Comment: How did you buy the game? Is this a download from the Microsoft store? Are you logged into Windows using a Microsoft account?

Comment: 1 year later and this game still crashes like every hour or few!

Answer (score 1):

Forza Horizon 4 is very picky in regards of applications that somehow interface with the game. So far I could reproduce this behavior with the following applications:

- FPS Monitor
- OBS Studio / Streamlabs OBS
- SimHub (works fine when launched with a running game)

Comment: I don't have any applications that interface with the game, I used to have some but I deleted them and then reinstalled the game and it still doesn't work.